# Canonical URL not redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, url, canonical-link

I want to get rid of the `www.` before my website name, so I tried setting a canonical URL tag in the files, but it didn't redirect me to http://blablabla.tk when I typed www.blablabla.tk

I tried this code: `<link rel="canonical" href="http://blablabla.tk" />`

Do I have to change something in the **.htaccess** file or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, add this to the top of the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.blablabla.tk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blablabla.tk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The **"canonical"** link that you have tells [clients like search engine indexing bots which version of the page is the "preferred" version](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394). It doesn't actually redirect anything.

Comment: Thanks, I had worked it out, but it is the correct answer, so people who might need it: use it!