# htaccess Canonical names redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-redirect

I'm running a website using an SSL certificate.

To optimize my SEO I would like to redirect all CNames to https://example.com.

There are 4 variants of the same address:
https: //example.com
https: //www.example.com
http: //example.com 
http: //www.example.com

This piece of code almost works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://example.com/$0 [R,L]
```

However, one of the URLs do not redirect. If I type just example.com (http://example.com) the URL does not redirect to https://example.com.

Could anyone help me out with the code above to rectify this?

In response to the answer from Jon below. I added the snippet of code to the existing .htaccess file. As I'm unfamiliar with .htaccess I wonder if the code around that snippet is causing the redirect loop?

Here is the .htaccess file including the snippet from below:

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Installation directory
    RewriteBase /

    # Protect application and system files from being viewed
    RewriteRule ^(application|modules|system|tests|sql) - [F,L]

    # Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
    RewriteRule .* index.php?kohana_uri=$0 [L,QSA]

    #redirect CNames to non www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://example.com/$0 [R,L]

   </IfModule>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Canonical URL not redirecting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763432/canonical-url-not-redirecting)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option:

```
# http www and non-www to https non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:www\.)?(.*)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%1/$1          [R=301,L]

# https www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%1/$1      [R=301,L]
```

I guess the best place for this code is below the `RewriteBase /` directive.

If there is a loop, it is hardly generated by the previous code. Maybe by the 2nd rule and you may try adding a condition, like this:

```
# Add next line before the rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !index\.php   [NC]
# Current rule
RewriteRule .* index.php?kohana_uri=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback but the feedback loop remained. I did do fiddle around though and THINK I have it working. I'm going to post a new question on that. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The HTTPS should be "off"

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://example.com/$0 [R,L]
```

Because you want either the host starts with www or HTTPS is OFF.

Comment: thanks for the answer but when I added that and navigated tot he site I received an error that said there was a "redirect-loop"?

Comment: @DougFirr Not sure why you're getting too many redirects, those rules work fine for me. Looking at your htaccess file though, you're going to want to put those rules **before** the rest of your rules.

Comment: thanks again for the feedback. Tried moving the snippet to the start of the .htaccess file but same result :-(
I wonder if it's a consequence of the CMS configuration. I know that int he config file there is a line of code to use https or http, this is meant to be managed in the back end. Hm, may try switching it off and seeing what that does

Comment: So tried switching off https in the back end to rely on the .htaccess file only. Same result. Thanks all the same Jon I appreciate it